# VideoVideo - Video Width x Height- MediaPlayer Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, media-player, android-videoview

I have written a sample app that reproduces the problem:

https://github.com/blundell/VideoRatioProblemPerDevice

The [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) documentation states:

> Displays a video file. ... takes care of computing its measurement from the video so that it can be used in any layout manager, and provides various display options such as scaling

**The problem is the Samsung Galaxy S3 is doing weird things to the video and not respecting the ratio of the video.** (also happening on an HTC device).

Activity with full screen fragment:

What I have found is when the video is played on the Samsung Galaxy S3 it will play in an incorrect ratio. It looks like it has been stretched to the height of the view without any regard for the ratio of the original video.

here:
[image: s3]

However if I play the video on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus the video is in the correct ratio.

here:
[image: n]

If I force the video to take up the full size of the fragment it looks ok on the S3 (because the ratio of the screen is the ratio of the video). However I don't want to do this as it **screws up the fragment being used in other places i.e. tablets**.

The code is:

An Activity with a Fragment with a VideoView. It can be seen here: [GITHUB CODE LINK](https://github.com/blundell/VideoRatioProblemPerDevice/tree/master/src/com/example/videotest)

if you want some code here is hte VideoPlayerFragment:

```
public class VideoPlayerFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "VideoPlayer";

    private FitVideoView videoView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_player, container, false);

        videoView = (FitVideoView) root.findViewById(R.id.surface);

        return root;
    }

    public void playVideo() {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test_vid);
        Log.d(TAG, "Uri is: " + uri);
        setVideoLocation(uri);
        if (!videoView.isPlaying()) {
            videoView.start();
        }
    }

    private void setVideoLocation(Uri uri) {
        try {
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "VideoPlayer uri was invalid", e);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void pauseVideo() {
        if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
            videoView.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try switching from `VideoView` to `MediaPlayer` and a `SurfaceView`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I haven't, you think there is that much difference? I'll give it a go. Means I have to look after the state more myself.

Comment: Somewhere, manufacturers have tinkered. The one spot they could have tinkered that is relatively easy for you to recover from is if they tinkered with `VideoView`. You could even just grab the `VideoView` source code, drop it in your project (refactored into your package), switch to using your copy, and see what happens. If the problem is fixed, then stick with your private `VideoView`. If the problem persists, then the issue is deeper in the media playback stuff (a.k.a., "here there be dragons").

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah true. Tried pulling in `VideoView`, needed `MediaPlayer` which needed `Metadata` which was ok. However MediaPlayer `System.loadLibrary("media_jni");` loads a native library and gives me an `unsatisfied link error`. So I am going to try the `MediaPlayer` and `SurfaceView` route.

Comment: Wow, `VideoView` got a lot more complicated than the last time I looked at it. It used to be ~200 lines of code, simply a wrapper around `MediaPlayer` and `SurfaceView`. Sorry to steer you in the wrong direction on that front.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's ok. I implemented MediaPlayer and SurfaceView, it gave the same result. Which is good because it means the fault is elsewhere (or lower down). I'm starting to think the issue could be in the video file. I updated the GitRepo with my results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this issue occurs with `VideoView` and with `MediaPlayer` + `SurfaceView`.

**When the system asks the video for it's width x height it is returning 640x480 when it should be returning 852x480.**

i.e.

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.getVideoWidth();
    mp.getVideoHeight();
}
```

This is either a bug in the `MediaPlayer` handling of the video container/codec or an issue with the video file itself.

[image: GSpot Details]

Either way I have circumvented it by adding what I know the video's width and height is to my code. I have updated the [Git Repo](https://github.com/blundell/VideoRatioProblemPerDevice) with this fix. **hack alert**

Here's a link to the question where I found out the [different size details of my video](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5819/how-does-gspot-calculate-recommended-display-size).

You can apply this fix to the `VideoView` or directly to `MediaPlayer` + `SurfaceView` your choice. Here's the `VideoView` answer:

```
public class FitVideoView extends VideoView {

    private final int mVideoWidth = 853;
    private final int mVideoHeight = 480;
    private boolean applyFix = true;

    public FitVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FitVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public FitVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (applyFix) { // A Toggle so I can see both results
            // This doesn't ask the video for it's size, but uses my hardcoded size
            applyFix(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        } else {
            // This asks the video for its size (which gives an incorrect WxH) then does the same code as below
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    private void applyFix(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = getDefaultSize(mVideoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getDefaultSize(mVideoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (mVideoWidth > 0 && mVideoHeight > 0) {
            if (mVideoWidth * height > width * mVideoHeight) {
                Log.d("TAG", "image too tall, correcting");
                height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
            } else if (mVideoWidth * height < width * mVideoHeight) {
                Log.d("TAG", "image too wide, correcting");
                width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "aspect ratio is correct: " + width + "/" + height + "=" + mVideoWidth + "/" + mVideoHeight);
            }
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "setting size: " + width + 'x' + height);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a bug I think as I have this problem with a specific video that has width and height of 640x480 and 853x480 too in it's Metadata. Code must read width from video track header or TKHD Metadata. I will post an separate answer soon.