# Video width is different in different devices

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, media-player

I have a special video when i want to get this video's width code returns different value for Samsung galaxy s6 and Samsung note 3. I tested many different codes and libraries, but result is the same.
in Samsung galaxy s6: 640x480
in Samsung note 3: 853x480
when I open this video with [Gspot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) program it shows:

> Recommended Display Size: 853x480

and this is the same value is returned by our IOS app tested in Iphone 7. aspect radio is not the same and this is big problem.

here is some of codes I tested:

(1)

```
    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    metaRetriever.setDataSource(path);
    Bitmap bmp = metaRetriever.getFrameAtTime(-1);

    int height = bmp.getHeight();
    int width = bmp.getWidth();
```

(2)

```
    MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(ApplicationLoader.applicationContext, 
                                     Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));

    width = myMediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
    height = myMediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
```

(3)

```
 MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriever.setDataSource(path);
 String heights = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        String widths = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
    int height = Integer.valueOf(heights);
        int width = Integer.valueOf(widths);
```

(4)

```
  MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(ApplicationLoader.applicationContext, Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
            myMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener((mp, width, height) -> {
        int videoWidth = width;
        int videoHeight = height;
    );
            myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            myMediaPlayer.prepare();
```

[FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever), [FFmpeg Java](https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper), [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) and some other libraries returns the same result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14303137/6347620

Answer (score 0):

try to scale images with DPI scale of device, i had same problem with premade bitmaps original pixel width was scaled like that.